# worklight invoking procedure in a loop error

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm trying to delete a row in a table after I insert the information about that row into the database, and then I delete it.

But the problem is that the row won't be deleted because it seems the WL invoke procedure run in the background process, so the loop keep running until it reaches the end before the procedure can be done. is there any way so that the loop could wait the invoking procedure finish first, and then continue the loop?

here is my code

```
 var table = document.getElementById('table_cart');
 for (var r = 1, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
     var barcode = table.rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML;
     var name = table.rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML;
     var total = table.rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML;
     var price = table.rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML;
     var invocationData = {
         adapter: 'ProductAdapter',
         procedure: 'add',
         parameters: [barcode, total, price] //nama produk,jmlh
     };
     WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
         onSuccess: function (response) {
             alert(total + " " + name + " order success");
             //table.rows[r].innerHTML = "";
             //table.removeChild(table.rows[r]);

             //table.deleteRow(r);//blm bisa apus cartnya
             alert(r);
             document.getElementById('table_cart').deleteRow(r);
         },
         onFailure: function (response) {
             alert("error connecting to server");
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Worklight all procedure calls are asynchronous - so when writing 2 procedure calls one after another you cannot know if the last call finished.
If you want to make sure that your next procedure call happens only after the first one finished you should put the second procedure call inside the onSuccess callback method of your first call.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think what you want to do is to remove the row from the HTML after you add it to the database, so what I think you should do is only progress to the next row (r++) on the onSuccess of the adapter request. There you delete the row from the HTML and only then progress to the next row.

Comment: I tried to delete the row on the onSuccess, but it won't delete, because it is asynchronous. by the time the invoke Procedure finished, the loop has already finish, therefore the r value is always at the end of the loop